# Intent-filter: write an android:pathPattern that catches all URLs within a domain

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, intentfilter

I am writing an Android app for a product, which has a domain, say, `example.com`. What I want is for my app to start whenever a user is trying to access any URL within this domain in any browser, like

- `example.com`
- `example.com/`
- `example.com/path1`
- `example.com/path1/`
- `example.com/path1/path2`
- `example.com/path1/path2/`
  ... and so on.

Not only do I want the app to start when a user clicks on a link, but also when they type the desired URL manually into the address bar.

Of course, I've created an intent filter and use its `data` parameter for this purpose.

Seems to be a pretty easy task, but I cannot figure out which host (I mean, with `/` or without) and pathPattern/pathPrefix/path I have to specify. For each combination of these parameters that I try, some of the options stop working.

`pathPattern` seems to have some sort of weird syntax and has very little in common with normal regexps.

Comment: "Not only do I want the app to start when a user clicks on a link, but also when they type the desired URL manually into the address bar" -- I am not aware of any browsers that support this, though I haven't tried it recently. "I cannot figure out which host (I mean, with / or without) " -- no slash. "and pathPattern/pathPrefix/path I have to specify" -- none.

Comment: CommonsWare, no, it's not working when a URL has a trailing slash

Comment: If I type "example.com/abc" in the address bar, it works, but for "example.com/abc/" it doesn't

Comment: Well, stop testing using the address bar. As I wrote, that's not necessarily going to work anyway, let alone on every browser. Test using links on a Web page, or by forming your own `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` and calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I decided to abandon the address bar :)